# jquery hiding works in .live and fails in .ready

Tags: jquery, show-hide, ready

Both of the below functions (which are identical except for when they should run) are in `$(document).ready`. The `.live` version works as expected, hiding 2 divs when the selector is checked and showing them when it is unchecked. The `.ready` version does nothing but it is supposed to hide the specified divs when the page is loaded.  The checkbox 'allday' is checked by default (for testing purposes).

What is wrong with the `.ready` version?

```
$("input[name='allday']").ready(function(){ //OnLoad verify if allday is checked to disallow time entry
    if($(this).is(":checked")){ //There is a check
        $("#evst").hide(); //hide time entry
        $("#evet").hide();
    } else {
        $("#evst").show(); 
        $("#evet").show();
    }; 
}); 

$("input[name='allday']").live("click", function(){ //OnClick verify if allday is checked to disallow time entry
    if($(this).is(":checked")){ //There is a check
        $("#evst").slideUp(); //hide time entry
        $("#evet").slideUp();
    } else {
        $("#evst").slideDown(); 
        $("#evet").slideDown();
    }; 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use .ready `$(this)` won't refer to the right element - change it to `$("input[name='allday']")`

Comment: so really, I could just have a bare `if($("input[name='allday']").is(":checked")){...}` without the `selector.ready()` wrapper?

Comment: You'll still need .ready unless the code comes after the `<input>` in the HTML source.